# How to give users only editing their own content permission?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to built a system where users list their used books. I have built two independent tables and a lookup table to match the users with their listed books.

Login/Register system is completed. A CRUD system for the books was also built.

Now I want to give edit/delete permission only to the book owner but I have no idea how to match them w/o problem. How can I do that?

Comment: You have a lookup table, so can't you look up if a user owns the book and if so allow the editing?

Comment: When a request is made to perform an edit or delete on a record, check if the user making the request matches the owner of the record.  If they don't match, return an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
user_table
----------------------------
| UserID  | Username | ... |
----------------------------
| 1001    | Deniz    | ... |
----------------------------
| ....    | .....    | ... |
----------------------------

book_table
----------------------------
| BookID  | Bookname | ... |
----------------------------
| 5123    | SQL NOW  | ... |
----------------------------
| ...     | ...      | ... |
----------------------------

user_book_table
--------------------
| UserID  | BookID |
--------------------
| 1001    | 5123   |
--------------------
| ...     | ...    |
--------------------

SELECT * FROM user_table AS u, book_table AS b
  LEFT JOIN user_book_table USING(UserID)
  WHERE u.UserID = 1001
  AND b.BookID = 5123;
```

With this structure you can simply check if the book is owned by a user. If so, he/she may edit the book.